# the program is not executing as it should be?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, while-loop

this is my code 
"the full code"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RestTestGhada {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    RestGhada obj2 = new RestGhada("null",0,0,"null");
    RestGhada obj3 = new RestGhada();
    RestGhada obj4 = new RestGhada();
    DateGhada obj5 = new DateGhada(19,8,1998);
    DateGhada obj6 = new DateGhada(19,8,2011);
    WorkerGhada obj7 = new WorkerGhada("Ghada","Alghamdi",obj5,obj6,"Female");
    RestGhada obj8 = new RestGhada(12,"null",20,obj7);





    obj2.setID(123456789);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of employee: ");
    int noemp=input.nextInt();

    String empname[] = new String[5];
    System.out.print("Enter the employee names: ");
    for(int i=0;i<empname.length;i++)
        empname[i]=input.nextLine();
    obj2.setEmployeeName(empname);

    System.out.print("**Menu** \n"
            + "1.Create three objects of restaurant.\n"
            + "2.Display all restaurants information.\n"
            + "3.Display the checkRestaurant result. \n"
            + "4.Exit.\n"
            + "Your choice is: ");
    int choice =input.nextInt();
    while(choice!=4){

        switch(choice){
            case 1: obj3.setName("null");obj3.setID(choice);obj4.setNoEmployee(noemp); break;
            case 2: obj2.lastprint(); break;
            case 3: obj2.CheckRestaurant(noemp); break;
                }
        System.out.print("\n Your choice: ");
        choice=input.nextInt();
    } 

 CorporateGhada[] ArrGroups=new CorporateGhada[4];

               RestGhada obj1 = new RestGhada("KFC");

               ArrayList<RestGhada>ALRestaurant=new ArrayList();

               System.out.println("do you want to enter information?");   
               String c = input.nextLine();


               while (true){
               if(c.equals("no")||c.equals("No"))
               break;
               System.out.print("Menu\n"
                       + "1.enter ID,name,number of employee,owner\n"
                       + "2.enter ID,adress,name,owner,number of employee\n"
                       + "your choice :  ");
               int choice1 =input.nextInt();
               if(choice1 == 1){
               System.out.println("Enter ID") ;   
               int ID=input.nextInt();
               System.out.println("Enter name ") ;   
                String name=input.next();
              System.out.println("nbemployee:") ;   
               int nbemployee =input.nextInt(); 
               System.out.println("Enter owner:") ;   
               String owner=input.next();
               ALRestaurant.add(new RestGhada(name,ID,nbemployee,owner));
               }
               else if (choice1 == 2){
               System.out.println("Enter ID:");
               int ID=input.nextInt();
               System.out.println("Enter adrees:") ;   
               String adrees=input.next();
               System.out.println("Enter name :"); 
                String name=input.next();
               System.out.println("Enter owner:") ;   
               String owner=input.next();
               System.out.println("Enter nbemployee:");
               int nbemployee=input.nextInt();
                 ALRestaurant.add(new RestGhada(ID,adrees,name,owner,nbemployee)); 
               }
               else
                    ALRestaurant.add(new RestGhada());

               }


               ALRestaurant.remove(1);
               for(int i=0; i<ALRestaurant.size();i++ ){
               System.out.print(ALRestaurant.get(i));}
               System.out.print(ALRestaurant.contains(obj1));






}
```

}

when i try to run the first quistion doesn't take an answer and it get into the while loop directly.. i already take an information from the user before and it worked but now it's now.. 
when i run it it turns out like this :

```
do you want to enter information?

Menu

1.enter ID,name,number of employee,owner

2.enter ID,adress,name,owner,number of employee

your choice :
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For me, it is not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "not efficient"? Is the code slow or not working at all? What is the purpose of the code snippet? Can you reduce it to an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? And please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you type anything in the `input` before the first question was asked?
When I just run this (tried to turn your code into a working example) it waits for me to input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<RestGhada> ALRestaurant = new ArrayList();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("do you want to enter information?");
    String c = input.nextLine();


    while (true) {
        if (c.equals("no") || c.equals("No"))
            break;
        System.out.print("Menu\n"
                + "1.enter ID,name,number of employee,owner\n"
                + "2.enter ID,adress,name,owner,number of employee\n"
                + "your choice :  ");
        int choice1 = input.nextInt();
        if (choice1 == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter ID");
            int ID = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter name ");
            String name = input.next();
            System.out.println("nbemployee:");
            int nbemployee = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter owner:");
            String owner = input.next();
            ALRestaurant.add(new RestGhada(name, ID, nbemployee, owner));
        } else if (choice1 == 2) {
            System.out.println("Enter ID:");
            int ID = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter adrees:");
            String adrees = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter name :");
            String name = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter owner:");
            String owner = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter nbemployee:");
            int nbemployee = input.nextInt();
            ALRestaurant.add(new RestGhada(ID, adrees, name, owner, nbemployee));
        } else
            ALRestaurant.add(new RestGhada());

    }
}

private static class RestGhada {
    public RestGhada(int id, String adrees, String name, String owner, int nbemployee) {

    }

    public RestGhada() {

    }

    public RestGhada(String name, int id, int nbemployee, String owner) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you haven't included your initialisation of the input object. 
If you add the line

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

In the beginning of your program it should work. 
I ran your program with that line added and it worked.

Besides that you should really look up on correct indentation.

Comment: I haven't run it, as i don't have time before later today, but just reading through it, it seems fine. It still doesn't work when you run it?

Comment: yes still not working, maybe the problem is in the computer idk

Comment: Probably not in your computer. You could try debugging it to see where it hangs. You would probably learn a lot this way as well.
Edit: I would google "How to debug with x" - x being the environment you're programming in (IntelliJ, Eclipse, etc.)

Comment: My best guess is that somewhere in one of your objects you have a function causing the problem. Maybe Rhestghada.lastprint() or .CheckRestaurant().

Comment: Just saw your comment on another post. The error seems to be because you call nextInt, when there's not an integer in the input. This causes the Scanner to throw an error.

Comment: but i called nextLine to a string input?

Comment: The error is in these lines:
System.out.println("Enter name ");
String name = input.next();

input.next() just takes the next characther. So if you enter Ghada it takes 'G' then it moves on.. Then when you call .nextInt it still has "hada" in the input. then it tries reading an integer and fails. 
You should use .nextLine() instead @Ghada

Comment: got it! i did it as you said, the code that is in the while loop worked well, but the question still doesn't take an answer

Answer (score 0):

**change to this code.**

```
   System.out.println("do you want to enter information (yse/no) ? :");
    String c = input.nextLine();

         while (true) {
                    if (c.equals("no") || c.equals("No")){
                          break;
                    }
                    else{
                         System.out.println("Enter Your Choice(1 or 2) :");
                        int choice1 = input.nextInt();
                        if (choice1 == 1) {
                            System.out.println("Enter ID");
                            int ID = input.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter name ");
                            String name = input.next();
                            System.out.println("nbemployee:");
                            int nbemployee = input.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter owner:");
                            String owner = input.next();
                            ALRestaurant.add(new RestGhada(name, ID, nbemployee, owner));
                        } else if (choice1 == 2) {
                            System.out.println("Enter ID:");
                            int ID = input.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter adrees:");
                            String adrees = input.next();
                            System.out.println("Enter name :");
                            String name = input.next();
                            System.out.println("Enter owner:");
                            String owner = input.next();
                            System.out.println("Enter nbemployee:");
                            int nbemployee = input.nextInt();
                            ALRestaurant.add(new RestGhada(ID, adrees, name, owner, nbemployee));
                        } else{
                             ALRestaurant.add(new RestGhada());
                        }
                    }
    }
```

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at RestTestGhada.main(RestTestGhada.java:104)